# the Dropdown set value change rapidly with a flesh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp dropdown list, when I set the value by jquery it change to the default value rapidly with a flesh. my code is below.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMajorCategoriesID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" CssClass="required"></asp:DropDownList>

$("[id$='ddlMajorCategoriesID']").val(MajorCategoriesId);
```

any can help me Ihave tryed many way but can,t get its solution

Comment: wrap the code in ready event.

Comment: Milind Anantwar can you explain please I have bind the drop down already in the page load event but want to set the value on button click event in jquery

Comment: can you show us the click event you have written

Comment: <span class="spanedit" onclick="EditRecord(this);"></span>

Comment: var MajorCategoriesId = $.trim($(elem).closest("tr").find(".hdnMajorCategoriesId").val());

Comment: $("#ddlMajorCategoriesID").val(MajorCategoriesId);

Comment: Acutally I need a way to prevent the drop to go to the default selected value after setiing the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value when document is ready:

```
$(function(){
 $("[id$='ddlMajorCategoriesID']").val(MajorCategoriesId);
});
```

Comment: How can I use the ready function within another function sir My code is below 
<span class="spanedit" onclick="EditRecord(this);"></span>

function EditRecord(elem) {
                var ProcurementTypeId = $(elem).closest("tr").find(".hdnProcurementTypeId").val();
                var MajorCategoriesId = $.trim($(elem).closest("tr").find(".hdnMajorCategoriesId").val());
              
                $("[id$='ddlProcurementTypeId']").val(ProcurementTypeId);                           $("[id$='ddlMajorCategoriesID']").val(MajorCategoriesId);
               
                });
            }

Comment: @Tariq: can you create jsfiddle

Comment: No Sir but I have done it. thanks a lot for your help